# Pass @ModelAttribute to href Spring MVC

Tags: spring, model-view-controller

I'm attempting to pass a calculated URL from server-side via @ModelAttribute and sometimes the href attribute in html (where I allocate this @ModelAttribute) appears to be empty and need to do multiple ctrl-f5 for finally set the URL.

My controller has something like that:

```
@Controller
....
String calculatedURL = calculateURL(request, user);
if(StringUtils.isBlank(calculatedURL)){
throw new Exception("Error calculating URL");
}
model.addAttribute("calculatedURL",calculatedURL);
return "myPage";
```

And in my JSP:

```
<a href="${calculatedURL}">myLink</a>
```

The problem is that sometimes this href value is "".
I tried to evaluate if calculatedURL is null or blank in my controller and throw exception if is it. This never happens and calculatedURL allways is passed with value.

Thanks in advance and so sorry for my English.

David.

Comment: It is hard to predict the method's behavior, but does it need some state that is not bound to the request? Could you provide more info about this method?

Comment: Hi Diogo,Thanks for your response. I added this control before return the page and it never happens, so calculatedURL allways has value.